# Aura component: Adjust Table <TR> Heights

Tags: aura

I want to make the height of the rows the same size as the header of this picture
[image]

As you can see, the rows have a bigger height.
I've tried this but no success.

```
<tr id ="{!index}" style="font-size: 10px; height: 14.4pt;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options to do:

`!important` forces the style for the  tag.

```
<tr id ="{!index}" style="font-size: 10px; height: 14.4pt !important;">
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: didnt change anything adding the !important

Comment: did you try using px instead of pt for height? Is there a mandate to use pt? Also you might have to check the cell-padding/padding of the row. 

I can see from your screenshot that Quantity text-box is editable which could add padding. Also if there are additional columns with long content, then height adjustment might help.

Comment: thanks for helping but yet no success... Ive tried changing to px nothing changed.
Tried adding padding and cell-padding but stil nothing is being changed.

Comment: I've discovered that if I remove the lightning:input from it, it get smaller. So the input is causing the issue. However I need it there...

Comment: @JulioDidierMaciel have you tried adding `variant="label-hidden"` on the `lightning:input` tag ?